# MUX in a 4 bit by 3 bit memory

Tags: multiplexer, memory, ram

Here is a 3-bit adressable memory with an adress space of 4.
My question is why is the book calling the 3 rightmost highlighted circuits MUXes? And what type of MUXes are they? 4:1 MUX? And if it is so, it has to be like shown in this figure [image] but in the circuit below the AND gates are only fed with the adress wire coming from the decoder and the corresponding stored values, so how are these MUXes?
[image]

These figures are from a book called **Introduction to computing systems from bits and gates to C/C++ & beyond** by *Yale N. Patt and Sanjay J. Pattel*, Third Edition Published by McGraw-Hill Education

Comment: the circuit on left is a type of DEMUX ... the leftmost bar should really encompass the AND gates to the immediate right and the vertical line to the left ... the other three are MUXes with part of each MUX enclosed by the bar on the left

Comment: @jsotola wrong in what? doesn't this circuit do its job as a memory?
do you mean the circuit that the book called a MUX is a DEMUX? if that's what you mean the i dont agree since the DEMUX has more than one output (as far as  I know) which is not the case in the figure
also I honestly didn't understand your last sentence. can you edit the picture and post waht you mean as an answer?
 P.S: I still didn't learn the DEMUX yet, but I know it does the opposite job of a MUX

Comment: my comment has incorrect information ... please ignore it ... see the answer

Comment: @jsotola yes I saw your answer and I toatally agree with it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book identifies the MUX circuit correctly.

A MUX is a circuit that selects one input from a group of inputs and passes it to a common output.

How that selection is accomplished can vary, as long as only one input is selected at any one time.

In this example the selection is accomplished by four discrete terms.

The *Address Decoder* generates those four terms.

Overall, the Decoder and the MUX can also be thought of as a MUX that uses two address lines to select 1 of 4 inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5UUI6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sometimes things are clearer if you view only one element of a repeating series.

[image]

Comment: yeah I get it now so what the book calls a MUX is not the whole thing but only a part of that MUX, the other part is in the decoder AND gates which are the 2 select wires and the input wire is the one coming out of the S-R latch. is that correct?

Comment: not quite ... a MUX is a circuit that selects one input from a group of inputs ... how that selection is accomplished can vary

Comment: my comment made me realize that my answer was incorrect ... I updated it